# mis-positioning of favicon dragged-and-dropped on desktop 10.8.5

Tags: finder, desktop

Doing web research, I frequently collect .weblocs on my desktop, clicking on the favicon in a browser URL box,  dragging it to the spot I want, and dropping it there.  Until recently, the resulting .webloc file would always "stick" where I put it. (So, I could build up "piles" of .webloc icons -- not pretty but effective for quick-and-dirty searches.)  Now the .weblock files are ending up somewhere else, stacking up at center-right of my iMac's display.  (I guess that's the Finder's I-don't-know-where-to-put-it default for all items going on the desktop.)  This occurs for latest versions of FF, Safari, and Chrome.

Files and folders I drag and drop to the desktop still "stick" as before. Favicons dragged to open folders go where I put them, as before.

I think this started happening when I reconfigured my external screen to "be" on the left of the built-in display from being on the right.  That's the only fallout of this reconfiguration. Everything else about the side-by-side displays operates as expected.

How can I restore the old --and, I argue, correct-- operation, so .webloc files go where I put them?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This problem disappeared when I installed MacOS 10.9.